# KeyListeners for a JComboBox which is used as a cell editor in a table

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox, swingx

I am sorry if this sounds likes a basic question but I am relatively new to java. I have a JComboBox which I populate from a database and then use it in a JTable. I do that using the following code:

```
itemEditortxt = new JComboBox(buildComboBoxmodel("SELECT item_name FROM items ORDER BY item_name"));
AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(itemEditortxt);
TableColumn ledgerColumn = invoicePurchasedTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
ledgerColumn.setCellEditor(new ComboBoxCellEditor(itemEditortxt));
```

I am trying to add key listeners to the JComboBox but for some reason they are not being called when I press any key when the focus is on the cell which uses the JComboBox. Following is how I add the litterers:

```
itemEditortxt.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {System.out.print("line1");}
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {System.out.print("line2");}
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {System.out.print("line3");}
    });
```

Can someone please tell me what Im doing wrong? Thanks.
Following is the SSCCE. There are two similar JComboBoxes, one is added normally and the other is used as a cell editor. In the first one the user can use the keyboard arrows and then press ENTER in order to make a selection. This is not the case for the one in the table. Thanks:

```
package sp2;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.autocomplete.*;

class InvoicePurchasedModel extends DefaultTableModel {
public InvoicePurchasedModel (Vector<Vector<Object>> data, Vector<String> columnNames) {
    super(data, columnNames);
}

@Override
public Class getColumnClass(int col) {
    if (col == 0) 
        return String.class;
    else
        return Double.class;   
}
}

public class SP2 {    
JFrame mainPage;
JTabbedPane jtp;
JPanel mainPanel;
JPanel purchasedInvoicesPanel;    
RXTable invoicePurchasedTable;
DefaultTableModel invoicePurchasedtm;
JComboBox itemEditortxt;
JComboBox itemEditortxt2;

SP2() {
    mainPage = new JFrame("System");
    mainPage.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout());
    mainPage.setSize(1200, 1200);
    mainPage.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    createTabs();    
    mainPage.setVisible(true);
}

void createTabs() {
    jtp = new JTabbedPane();
    mainPanel = new JPanel();
    mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    mainPage.getContentPane().add(jtp);      
    purchasedInvoicesPanel = new JPanel();
    jtp.addTab("Purchased", purchasedInvoicesPanel);
    invoicePurchasedtm = buildInvoicePurchasedTableModel();
    invoicePurchasedTable = new RXTable(invoicePurchasedtm) {
        private final KeyStroke tabKeyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_TAB, 0); 
            public void changeSelection(int row, int column, boolean toggle, boolean extend)
            {
                super.changeSelection(row, column, toggle, extend);
                if (editCellAt(row, column))
                {
                    Component editor = getEditorComponent();
                    editor.requestFocusInWindow();
                }
            }
        }; 
    invoicePurchasedTable.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
    invoicePurchasedTable.setSelectAllForEdit(true);
    purchasedInvoicesPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(purchasedInvoicesPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    JPanel purchasedInvoicesPanel1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel purchasedInvoicesPanel2 = new JPanel();
    purchasedInvoicesPanel.add(purchasedInvoicesPanel1);
    purchasedInvoicesPanel.add(purchasedInvoicesPanel2);
    JScrollPane invoicePurchasedscrollPane = new JScrollPane(invoicePurchasedTable);
    invoicePurchasedTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(1000, 400));
    String[] names = {"aa", "aa1", "aa2", "bb", "bb1", "bb2"};
    itemEditortxt = new JComboBox(names);
    itemEditortxt2 = new JComboBox(names);
    AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(itemEditortxt);
    AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(itemEditortxt2);
    TableColumn ledgerColumn = invoicePurchasedTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
    ledgerColumn.setCellEditor(new ComboBoxCellEditor(itemEditortxt));
    purchasedInvoicesPanel1.add(itemEditortxt2);
    purchasedInvoicesPanel2.add(invoicePurchasedscrollPane);
}

public static DefaultTableModel buildInvoicePurchasedTableModel() {
    Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
    columnNames.add("Item");
    columnNames.add("Quantity");
    columnNames.add("Unit Price");
    columnNames.add("Amount");
    Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
    Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();
    vector.add("");
    vector.add(0.00);
    vector.add(0.00);
    vector.add(0.00);
    data.add(vector);
    return new InvoicePurchasedModel(data, columnNames);
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
           new SP2();
       } 
    });
}
}
```

Comment: ListSelectionListener instead of KeyListener

Comment: Are you trying to add a listener to the text box inside the combobox?

Comment: The problem is that in the jComboBox which is used in the table the user can not make a selection from the drop down list using the enter key. He has to use the mouse. I want a selection to be made by using the enter key. I tried using a ListSelectionListener and a DocumentListener but in both of these cases I do not know when the user presses enter. I tried to add a key listener to the popup menu as such:    BasicComboPopup popup = (BasicComboPopup)itemEditortxt.getAccessibleContext().getAccessibleChild(0);
        JList list = popup.getList();
        list.addKeyListener(new KeyListener()...

Comment: **don't** use KeyListener - especially not with a combo decorated with autocomplete (there's some heavy lifting done internally which most probably will interfere with yours). Instead explain **what** you want to achieve so we can suggest a proper solution

Comment: ahh, just read your comment and did a quick check: worksform. So it's time for a SSCCE that demonstrates the problem

Comment: I want the combo box which I use as a cell editor in the JTable to act like a normal combo box: The user can scroll down the list using the arrow keys and can use the autocomplete feature (these things already work) and (this is the part that is not working) the user should be able to make a selection when he presses the enter key. At the moment pressing the enter key while X is highlighted but Y is displayed in the Combobox text field will cause the focus to move to the next cell without changing the selected value from Y to X.

Comment: please edit your question to add further details (and don't forget the SSCCE :-). Repeating: the enter key worksforme, so there's probably something wrong elsewhere.

Comment: I have added the SSCCE. I appreciate your help.

Comment: remove your override of `changeSelection` and the enter on the autocomplete combo editor works as expected :)

Comment: I tried that but its still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the problem was caused by the AutoCompleteDecorator. I deactivated it and used instead the AutoCompletion.enable(employeeDelete). Now the ENTER and TAB keys work as expected. I appreciate all the comments that helped me.

Answer (score 1):

> "I am trying to add key listeners to the JComboBox but for some reason they are not being called when I press any key when the focus is on the cell which uses the JComboBox."

I think what you may be trying to do is add a listener to "text field" for the combobox. The first thing you need to do is actually get the editor component. then you can add a `DocumentListener` to the `Document` of the `JTextComponent`

```
JTextComponent editor = (JTextComponent) comboBox.getEditor().getEditorComponent();
editor.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener(){
    ...
});
```